# How to select from GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following which print correctly:

```
MonthNumber 
Users
UserHits
```

I need also to have printed a column from `Coefficient` from `dbo.ReportAudienceOverviews`

How to change the SQL?

```
 SELECT DATEPART(mm, S.DateProcessStatus) as MonthNumber,
     --S.DeviceId, 
     SUM(A.Users) as Users,
     SUM(A.UsersHits) as UserHits
    FROM dbo.ReportAudienceOverviews A 
     LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportProcessStatuses S
     ON S.StatusId = A.StatusId
     AND S.DateProcessStatus >= '2014' AND S.DateProcessStatus < '2015'
    --WHERE S.DeviceId = 1 AND A.Coefficient = 20
    GROUP BY
     DATEPART(mm, S.DateProcessStatus), S.DeviceId
     ORDER BY MonthNumber ASC, S.DeviceId ASC
```

Comment: There could, in general, be *multiple* values of `Coefficient` for the rows which combine to form a single output row from this query - so how should a specific value of `Coefficient` be selected? Or should they be e.g. added together?

Comment: You have several options, for example `Coefficient = MIN(A.Coefficient)` or `..MAX(Coefficient)` or `SUM(Coefficient)` or `AVG(Coefficient)`. If you want a specific row's `Coefficient` you have to explain your logic.

Comment: I am interested in MIN(A.Coefficient)

Comment: I don't get why you didn't just type `MIN(A.Coefficient)` into your statement instead of asking a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to include the column with `MIN(Coefficient)`(as mentioned in a comment):

```
SELECT DATEPART(mm, S.DateProcessStatus) as MonthNumber,
 --S.DeviceId, 
 SUM(A.Users) as Users,
 SUM(A.UsersHits) as UserHits,
 MIN(A.Coefficient) as Coefficient
FROM dbo.ReportAudienceOverviews A 
 LEFT JOIN dbo.ReportProcessStatuses S
 ON S.StatusId = A.StatusId
 AND S.DateProcessStatus >= '2014' AND S.DateProcessStatus < '2015'
--WHERE S.DeviceId = 1 AND A.Coefficient = 20
GROUP BY
 DATEPART(mm, S.DateProcessStatus), S.DeviceId
 ORDER BY MonthNumber ASC, S.DeviceId ASC
```